# Working with multiple models and collects - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application, I have an Articles table, a Facebook posts table, and a Tweets table. These provide me with three collects when queried.

E.g.

```
$articles = App\Article::get();
$tweet_posts= App\Facebook::get();
$facebook_posts= App\Twitter::get();
```

What I'm looking to do is display all of the articles, tweets and Facebook posts on one page, like a big news feed, sorted in date order.

The data is in separate tables and has separate models.

The **articles migration** looks like this:

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('excerpt')->nullable();
    $table->mediumText('content')->nullable();
    $table->string('featuredImage')->nullable();
    $table->mediumText('featuredVideo')->nullable();
    $table->string('author')->nullable();
    $table->string('readingTime', 15)->nullable();
    $table->string('category')->nullable();
    $table->string('published')->default('pending');
    $table->boolean('featuredArticle')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and the **Facebook and Twitter migrations** look like this:

```
Schema::create('facebook_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->mediumText('content')->nullable();
    $table->string('featuredImage')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('twitter_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->mediumText('content')->nullable();
    $table->string('featuredImage')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

In this scenario, the Facebook and Twitter tables have significantly fewer data attributes in terms of fields than an Article.

Essentially what I would like to do is have one `foreach loop` to go through everything in all three tables and then assign styling based on the model type.

So, is it possible to merge 3 collections into one big collection and then just have null values for additional fields that some models don't have?

In the view (if everything were merged) I'd envision something like this:

```
@foreach($feeds as $feed)
    @if($feed->type == 'tweet')
    // Twitter styled block
        {{ $feed->title }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Where feed is the merged collection and `->type` is a global query scope to get the model type. E.g. App\Article.

Alternatively, if I were to return the view with three collections, would there be a way to order the items in date order but not limiting to collection type?

E.g. If tweet 1 was before Facebook post 3, could it sit in the middle?

Comment: You can merge collections by `$merged = $original->merge($latest);` but the data structure from each collection should be consistent. You could base your main collection on the largest schema, and then add `NULL` values if data does not exist

Comment: A polymorphic relationship would be useful for this situation, where each Facebook, Twitter and Article model would be `postable`. I would also use separate partials views that render each item depending on the type. Each partial would know about the model attributes it needed.